# How to output Prediction Values into an Excel File?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

new to scikit-learn and I want to take the prediction values and convert it back to text and output it into an excel file.

The way the project is setup is it takes a row of strings and predicts whether or not the column is a certain category (there is approximately 5 categories).

| Description | Actual Answer | Prediction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Some string that is random in length per row | Car | Truck |

I want to have the excel file output something like you see above. I do not want to output the numerical prediction results. I want to output the actual text itselfs.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

This is my code so far:

```
X = df['without_Tags']
Y = df['Tower']

tokens = Tokenizer()
VectorX = tokens.texts_to_sequences(df['without_Tags'].values)
VectorX = pad_sequences(VectorX, maxlen=200)
VectorY = pd.get_dummies(df['Tower'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(VectorX, VectorY, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

# Model Creation
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
CSV = pd.DataFrame({
    "Prediction": y_pred
})

CSV.to_csv("prediction.csv", index=False)
```

The file will be named "prediction.csv" and will be saved in your source code file directory.

Update:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"])
csv.to_csv("pred.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am getting this error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: CSV = pd.DataFrame({
    "Prediction": [y_pred]
}) Try wrapping y_pred around [] to make it a list

Comment: It compiled but the output inside the excel file is only [[0 0 1 0 0].

Comment: Can you tell the type of y_pred, also the value of y_pred

Comment: Type is: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Shape of numpy array?

Comment: Shape of VectorX: (495, 200),
Shape of VectorY: (495, 5) (VectorY is numpyarray)

Comment: shape of y_pred?

Comment: Shape of Y_Pred (99, 5). Test Size is set to 20%

Comment: Do this: import pandas as pd
csv = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"])
csv.to_csv("pred.csv", index=False), I am updating an edit in the post see it over there

Comment: In the excel file, it prints 1, 0, 0, 0, 0... for 100 rows. https://ibb.co/5WXYbsM this is how it shows

Comment: csv.to_csv("pred.csv", mode='a', header=False, index=False) Try this

Comment: Same thing, it just removes the heading, "1st, 2nd, 3rd"

Comment: @revive I just saw the screenshot, the previous method was correct, try printing y_pred. It might be your predictions that's causing the issue

Comment: I printed the y_pred. it shows the same thing as the screenshot.

Comment: So, I guess your problem is solved now. You now need to improve your algorithm to predict better.